# Combine MATCH with OR clause in the WHERE statement

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, where-clause, fts3

I want to perform a query in which the `WHERE` clausule has the following condition:

- one `MATCH` condition over a column in a `FTS3` table
  OR
- another not `MATCH` condition over a column in a non `FTS` table.

**Example**:

Say that I have two tables

- *books_fts*, which is a table with a *content* column for full text search.
- *books_tags*, which is non `FTS` table with tags.

I want to search *all the books that either contain 'Dikjstra' in their content or are tagged with the 'algorithm' word*. So I run this query:

```
SELECT * from books_fts               
LEFT OUTER JOIN books_tags ON books_fts.fk_id = books_tags.id
WHERE (books_fts MATCH 'content:%Dijkstra*')
OR (books_tags.tag = 'algorithm')
```

I think the query is right, and if I run it with either one of the `OR` clausules, it works.
However, when running it with the two clausules I get the following error:

```
unable to use function MATCH in the requested context
```

Seems to me that I cannot combine a `MATCH` with a non `MATCH` in the `WHERE` clause, even if each of them apply to different tables (one `FTS` and another non `FTS`). 
Is this true? I cannot find information on it.

NOTE: if the causules are separated with `AND` instead of `OR` the query is valid.

Thanks.

Comment: Did u find any workaround please?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's a known issue in SQL:

http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/FTS3-bug-with-MATCH-plus-OR-td50714.html

Comment: The link is dead. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Any workaround please?

Comment: Pinging @SaurabhSharma to see my answer. SO won't let me "at" two people so... just gotta hope Vapid sees this.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL worked for me

```sql
select 
  *
from 
  "card" 
  inner join "note" on "card"."noteId" = "note"."id" 
  inner join "noteFtsTag" on "noteFtsTag"."rowid" = "note"."rowid" 
  inner join "cardFtsTag" on "cardFtsTag"."rowid" = "card"."rowid" 
where 
  (
    "noteFtsTag"."rowid" in (
      select 
        "rowid" 
      from 
        "noteFtsTag" 
      where 
        "noteFtsTag"."tags" match ?
    ) 
    or "cardFtsTag"."rowid" in (
      select 
        "rowid" 
      from 
        "cardFtsTag" 
      where 
        "cardFtsTag"."tags" match ?
    )
  )
```

Source: https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost?udc=1&name=1a2f2ffdd80cf795